# How to prevent legend labels being cut off in Google charts

Tags: charts, legend, google-visualization

With a Perl script I generate numerous [Google Line Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart) for 20 and more series of data at once.

The legend labels are of the form: a serial number appended by an iterating #counter.

Unfortunately, starting with #10 those counters are cut off:

[image]

Is there maybe a way to stop Google charts from doing that?

My quite simple chart code is below:

```
    var data = { ...... };

    function drawCharts() {
            for (var csv in data) {
                    var x = new google.visualization.DataTable(data[csv]);

                    var options = {
                            title: csv,
                            width: 800,
                            height: 600
                    };

                    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById(csv));
                    chart.draw(x, options);
            }
    }

    $(function() {
            google.setOnLoadCallback(drawCharts);
    });
```

Comment: have you tried changing the options for `ChartArea`? Try setting `ChartArea.Right` to various values and see if it still cuts off.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

To get full legend in your chart just add chartArea width and height as below

```
var options = {
              title: csv,
              width: 800,
              height: 600,
              chartArea: {  width: "50%", height: "70%" }
};
```

Take a look at this [jqfaq.com](http://jqfaq.com/how-to-prevent-legend-labels-being-cut-off-in-google-charts/) to get a working sample

Comment: Expanding the chartArea option to a width of 100% solved the problem for me. Contrary to the documentation, the chartArea does include the legend. I used a PieChart but the same option is available for the LineChart.  var options = {'title':title,'width':w,'height':h,'chartArea':{left:0,top:10,width:"100%"}};
var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById(chartDiv));
chart.draw(data,options);

Comment: For some reason, this chartArea command is affecting nothing for us. Here is how we are sending it.  'chartArea': {'width': '100%', 'height': '20%'}  Any other ideas would be great.

Answer (score 0):

in chartArea, make width 30 percent move the graph to the center.

chartArea: {  width: "30%", height: "50%" }