# remove the ellipses in google barchart

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I am using google Bar Chart and the text on the side is not showing fully. Is there a way to remove the ellipses?

[image]

```
   google.charts.load('current', {'packages': ['corechart']});
   google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

   function drawChart() {
        var byCollege = {!! $byCollege !!};
        var info = [];
        var Header = ['Element', 'الخريجين'];
        info.push(Header);
        for (const elem of byCollege) {
            var temp = [];
            temp.push(elem['college_name']);
            temp.push(elem['total']);
            info.push(temp);
        }
        drawBarChart(info, 'piechart_college');
    }

  function drawBarChart(info, charId) {
        var view = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(info);
        var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById(charId));
        chart.draw(view);
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prevent legend labels being cut off in Google charts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16980002/how-to-prevent-legend-labels-being-cut-off-in-google-charts)

Comment: provide enough space for the legend using `chartArea`, as in the above answer, or move the legend position to top or bottom...